# In the context of inheritance in C++, how can a function in the derived class be invoked before the execution of the base class constructor?

Tags: design-patterns, c++17

this is an example program to demonstrate adapter pattern.
In the context of inheritance in C++, how can a function in the derived class be invoked before the execution of the base class constructor?

`AdapterInterface(int d, double r) : LegacyInterface(_w, _h)`

I was looking for a solution to execute `diagToRectConverter`
before `LegacyInterface(_w, _h)`  call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// Desired interface (calculate rect based on diagonal and ratio)
class NewInterface
{
public:
    NewInterface() { std::cout << "NewInterface ctr" << std::endl; }
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

// Legacy component (Adaptee)
class LegacyInterface
{
public:
    LegacyInterface(double w, double h) : _w(w), _h(h) { std::cout << "LegacyInterface ctr" << std::endl; }

    void oldDraw()
    {
        std::cout << "--LegacyInterface--" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Width    : " << _w;
        std::cout << "  Height   : " << _h << std::endl;
    }

private:
    double _w;
    double _h;
};

// Adapter wrapper
class AdapterInterface : public NewInterface, private LegacyInterface
{
public:
    AdapterInterface(int d, double r) : LegacyInterface(_w, _h)
    {
        std::cout << "AdapterInterface ctr" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "--New Interface--" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Diagonal : " << d;
        std::cout << "  Ratio    : " << r << std::endl;
        diagToRectConverter( d,  r);
    }

    void diagToRectConverter(int d, double r)
    {
        // Calculate the square of the diagonal
        double D_squared = double(d * d);

        // Calculate the width and height
        _w= std::sqrt(D_squared / (1 + r * r));
        _h = r * _w;
    }

    void draw() override
    {
        LegacyInterface::oldDraw();
    }

private:
    double _w;
    double _h;
};

int main()
{
    int d;
    double r = 1.7778;
    std::cout << "Enter Diagonal: ";
    std::cin >> d;
    NewInterface *adapter = new AdapterInterface(d, r);
    adapter->draw();

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to find an alternative approach that avoids calling `diagToRectConverter` twice in the constructor initialization of `LegacyInterface` within `AdapterInterface` for the given d and r values.

`AdapterInterface(int d, double r)  : LegacyInterface(std::get<0>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)), std::get<1>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)))`

Comment: Perhaps add *another* parent class, which needs to be first in the inheritance list. This new parent class then contains the `_w` and `_h` members, which are then calculated by the parent class constructor. And use those parent class members for the initialization of the `LegacyInterface`.

Comment: `class Calc {  
 //calculates the _w and _h by calling  diagToRectConverter
} 

// Adapter wrapper
class AdapterInterface : public Calc, public NewInterface , private LegacyInterface
{
public:
    AdapterInterface(int d, double r) : Calc(d, r) , LegacyInterface(Calc::_w ,Calc::_h)
    {
        std::cout << "AdapterInterface ctr" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "--New Interface--" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Diagonal : " << d;
        std::cout << "  Ratio  : " << r << std::endl;
    }

    void draw() override
    {
        LegacyInterface::oldDraw();
    }
}; `

Comment: ^^ Like this  ? 
@some-programmer-dude

Comment: Something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks, 
yes it is working as expected.
Is there any other way to do that  without introducing a new class ?

Comment: It looks like there are two completely different questions here mixed together.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then _w and _h are duplicated between this new class and LegacyInterface.

Comment: @ n. m. could be an AI

'AdapterInterface(int d, double r)  : LegacyInterface(std::get<0>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)), std::get<1>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)))' 

This approach was working for me , but it wasn't good enough.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI To be honest they are duplicated in the original code shown in the question as well. Which I didn't notice... :)

Comment: what is the best way to demonstrate adapter-pattern   without modifying
'class LegacyInterface'   

Comment: @Jestin or bridge pattern. There usally is a deferred initialization in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every problem can be solved by adding another level of indirection.

```
struct LegacyInterfaceWrapper : LegacyInterface
{
    LegacyInterfaceWrapper(std::pair<double, double> wh) : 
      LegacyInterface(std::get<0>(wh), std::get<1>(wh)) {}
};  

class AdapterInterface : public NewInterface, private LegacyInterfaceWrapper                      
{                                                                                                           
  public:
    AdapterInterface(int d, double r) : 
       LegacyInterfaceWrapper(diagToRectConverter(d, r)) {}
  // ...
```

`diagToRectConverter` need not be a member of anything and should return a pair rather than assign any instance or global variables.

```
  std::pair<double, double> diagToRectConverter(int d, double r)
  {
      // Calculate the square of the diagonal
      double D_squared = double(d * d);

      // Calculate the width and height
      double w = std::sqrt(D_squared / (1 + r * r));
      double h = r * w;
      return {w, h};
  }
```

Duplicate `_w` and `_h` members are no longer needed.

Comment: `struct LegacyInterfaceWrapper : LegacyInterface
{
    LegacyInterfaceWrapper(std::pair<double, double> wh) : 
      LegacyInterface(wh.first, wh.second) {}
};
// Adapter wrapper
class AdapterInterface :public NewInterface, private LegacyInterfaceWrapper
{
public:
 AdapterInterface(int d, double r) : LegacyInterfaceWrapper(diagToRectConverter(d, r))`


This solution works , better than `LegacyInterface(std::get<0>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)), std::get<1>(diagToRectConverter(d, r)))`